# An 'antd' form item default value from a map

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using *[antd](https://ant.design/docs/spec/introduce)* in React to make a form. I have a `form.item` which maps a response from the API and makes a `select.option`. Code:

```
<Form.Item
    name="companies"
    label="Hospital: "
    rules={[
        {
            required: true,
            message: 'Por favor, selecione uma empresa!',
        },
    ]}
>

    <Select
        showSearch
        placeholder="Empresa"
        style={{ width: '175px' }}
        onChange={fillDepartments}
    >

        {allCompanies?.map((company) => (
            <Select.Option key={company.id} value={company.id}>
                {company.name}
            </Select.Option>
        ))}
    </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

I have to set a default value to this select, but, I already tried map and filter on prop "DefaultValue" and "InitialValue" but both don't work.

AllCompanies, returns a array of items like this:

```
{
    company.id: string
    company.name: string
}
```

Comment: `defaultValue` is set on `Select` like so `<Select defaultValue={"7"} > ...code... </Select>`. using `"7"` since your value is an `id` type of `string`. Since you are using forms, you should be using `initialValue` on `Form.Item` like so `<Form.Item initialValue={"7"}> ...code... </Form.Item>`. Again, using `"7"` for same reason. But this way you hardcode `"7"` as a value. If you want a default value to be the first one in the array then instead of `"7"` you cna simply do `allCompanies[0]?.id`. this way the default will be the first one.

Comment: @Lith, Already tried that, but the page keep loading without initialValue, if i remove de ? i receive a error that initialValue Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: You should use `id` not `name` as on `Select.Option` your `value` is `company.id`. Also, if you start out `allCompanies` as an empty array then you should do a conditional render to only render the `Form.Item` when `allCompanies` has values. Since you are loading it asap as empty what happends is the `Form.Item` loads with default value of `undefined` as `allCompanies` is empty, after re-remder `allCompanies` obtains values but the default value can not be changed. `allCompanies.length > 0 && <Form.Item> ...` or some other form of render condition.

Comment: @Lith, makes sense! It worked, ty. Now i have another trouble, to advance steps in the form i need to call another hook,. there's a way i can set the initialValue then call that hook? would be something like initialValue: allCompanies[1].name then fillDepartaments (hook name)

Comment: @Lith already solved, ty for you help!!!